# Extract associative array index name to automatch the database column name

Tags: php, mysqli

Below is my code -

```
$insert_details = array("username"=>"pavan", "firstname"=>"pavan", "lastname"=>"r", "profile_about"=>"My name is Pavan R.");
$connection->insert($insert_details);    

        public function insert(array $insert_details) {

            $insert_query = "INSERT INTO user (username,firstname,lastname,profile_about) VALUES ($insert_details['username'],$insert_details['firstname'],$insert_details['lastname'],insert_details['profile_about'])";
            $run_insert_query = mysqli_query($this->mysql_con, $insert_query);

            if ($run_insert_query) {

                $select_query = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                $run_select_query = mysqli_query($this->mysql_con, $select_query);

                while ($selected_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_select_query)) {
                    $id = $selected_row['id'];
                    $username = $selected_row['username'];
                    $firstname = $selected_row['firstname'];
                    $lastname = $selected_row['lastname'];
                    $profile_about = $selected_row['profile_about'];
                }

                $es_insert = array();
                $es_insert['body']  = array('id' => $id, 'username' => $username, 'firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname, 'profile_about' =>  $profile_about);
                $es_insert['index'] = 'test';
                $es_insert['type']  = 'jdbc';
                $es_insert['id']    = $id;
                $check_insert = $this->es_con->index($es_insert);

                if($check_insert) {
                    echo nl2br("Successfully inserted to both database and elasticsearch\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                echo nl2br("Failed to insert into database hence closing the connection\n");            
            }
        }
```

When I run the code I get the following error -

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /var/www/html/es/combined.php on line 38
```

This is because of the SQL query ($insert_query). Can someone please help me debug this?

Also is there a way to extract the index names from array and pass it to database fields.In the above code, I've declared an associative array with index names same as my database column names. Is it possible to get those array index names and optimize the SQL query to just -

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ($insert_details['username'],$insert_details['firstname'],$insert_details['lastname'],insert_details['profile_about'])";
```

It should automatically extract the suitable column names from the array index name.

Comment: You need to remove the lines on top of the public function aswell.

Comment: *"Can someone please help me debug this?"* You will first need to show that you put in significant effort yourself (including researching the error) and it would certainly be helpful to show what line 38 is.

Comment: I've declared the function inside a class and function is called outside class.

Comment: Should we **guess which line is line 38** Kinda difficult as you only put 36 lines in your example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot quote array keys in `"`-quoted strings:

```
php > echo "$arr['foo']";
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in php shell code on line 1
```

Either go with

```
$sql = "... $insert_details[username] ..."
                            ^-------^---no quotes
```

or

```
$sql = "... {$insert_details['username']} ..."
            ^---------------------------^---brace syntax
```

And note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Is it possible to get those array index names and optimize the SQL query to just - `$insert_query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ($insert_details['username'],$insert_details['firstname'],$insert_details['lastname'],insert_details['profile_about'])";`It should automatically extract the suitable column names from the array index name.

Comment: technically, yes. use a prepared statement and bind your placeholders to the individual array elements, but that's not 'automatic'.

Comment: Can you please explain me with an example.